# Android sqlite to file.sql

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to dump dump a sqlite db into an file.sql on an android app.

I need to backup the db not by copying the db file, but by dumping it to an .sql file that can be inserted into an existing db.

Thanks
Avi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19460988/2299040 might help

Comment: Thanks but not exactly.  any other ideas?